# Experiencing a bug with this Batch code

Tags: batch-file, debugging, rainmeter

I'm using batch to make a program that notifies when someone is on their ftp server. Now I have a script that checks then sends a command to rainmeter's NXT-OS skin to open up a notifier. It does this by trying to download a file from the ftp server, because if the file is there it means the user is online. If it isn't there then we know it is not. I have it set so the files do not exist. However right now I am experiencing a bug where it makes the whistle sound of a notification without any popup box. Can someone look at this code and see how it could be sending half of a command when nobody is online? Thanks! Note: The included code is not the whole thing since the code includes ftp server addresses and passwords. Thanks!

[Get Rainmeter](https://www.rainmeter.net/)

(Run on Windows)

[Get NXT-OS](http://nxtos.com/)

```
Rem This is where it checks if the files were downloaded
if exist on.%friend1% set Friend1Stat=On
if exist on.%friend2% set Friend2Stat=On
if exist on.%friend3% set Friend3Stat=On
if exist on.%friend4% set Friend4Stat=On
if exist on.%friend5% set Friend5Stat=On


if exist on.%friend1% set /p Friend1Name=<on.%friend1%
if exist on.%friend2% set /p Friend2Name=<on.%friend2%
if exist on.%friend3% set /p Friend3Name=<on.%friend3%
if exist on.%friend4% set /p Friend4Name=<on.%friend4%
if exist on.%friend5% set /p Friend5Name=<on.%friend5%
if not exist log.txt echo. >log.txt
echo %time% %date% >>log.txt
set >>log.txt

if %Friend1Stat%==on goto friend1
goto friend1b
:back1
if %friend2stat%==on goto friend2
goto friend2b
:back2

if %friend3stat%==on goto friend3
goto friend3b
:back3

if %friend4stat%==on goto friend4
goto friend4b
:back4

if %friend5stat%==on goto friend5
goto friend5b
:back5

echo Complete. Waiting 60 seconds before starting again.
choice /c q /d q /t 60 /n
goto TESTFORFRIENDS

:friend1
if %friend1run%==yes goto back1
set friend1run=yes
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend1', style = 2, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend1name% is Online', body = '%friend1name% is on their computer.%time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back1

:friend1b
if %Friend1run%==no goto back1
set friend1run=no
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend1', style = 2, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend1name% is Offline', body = '%friend1name% is no longer on their computer. %time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back1

:friend2
if %friend2run%==yes goto back2
set friend2run=yes
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend2', style = 2, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend2name% is Online', body = '%friend2name% is on their computer.%time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back2

:friend2b
if %Friend2run%==no goto back2
set friend2run=no
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend2', style = 2, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend2name% is Offline', body = '%friend2name% is no longer on their computer. %time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back2


:friend3
if %friend3run%==yes goto back3
set friend3run=yes
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend3', style = 3, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend3name% is Online', body = '%friend3name% is on their computer.%time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back3

:friend3b
if %Friend3run%==no goto back3
set friend3run=no
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend3', style = 3, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend3name% is Offline', body = '%friend3name% is no longer on their computer. %time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back3

:friend4
if %friend4run%==yes goto back4
set friend4run=yes
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend4', style = 4, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend4name% is Online', body = '%friend4name% is on their computer.%time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back4

:friend4b
if %Friend4run%==not goto back4
set friend4run=no
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend4', style = 4, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend4name% is Offline', body = '%friend4name% is no longer on their computer. %time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back4

:friend5
if %friend5run%==yes goto back5
set friend5run=yes
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend5', style = 5, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend5name% is Online', body = '%friend5name% is on their computer.%time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back5

:friend5b
if %Friend5run%==not goto back5
set friend5run=no
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'Online-Friend5', style = 5, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = '%friend5name% is Offline', body = '%friend5name% is no longer on their computer. %time%'})" "nxt-os\Notify"
goto back5




:nosettings
"C:\Program files\Rainmeter\rainmeter.exe" ^!CommandMeasure "Notify" "notify({name = 'ITCMD', group = 'no-settings', style = 2, sound = 1, icon = 'Resources\\Images\\Welcome.png', title = 'Set Up ITCMD Notifier', body = 'Open the Location of the Notifier and edit settings.ini Then Restart the program.'})" "nxt-os\Notify"

echo :: Set Friend Usernames here! (Users set their own usernames) >settings.ini
echo. >>settings.ini
echo set Friend1=Set>>settings.ini
echo set Friend2=Set>>settings.ini
echo Set Friend3=Set>>settings.ini
echo Set Friend4=Set>>settings.ini
echo Set Friend5=Set>>settings.ini
echo. >>settings.ini
echo. >>settings.ini
echo :: Note: Do not change anything but the friend uernames! Fatal errors could occur. >>settings.ini
exit /b
```

Thanks a bunch in advance! If you have any questions let me know!

Comment: `if %Friend1Stat%==on goto friend1` never goes to `friend1` as `set Friend1Stat=On` and `if` is case sensitive. Use `if /I`, or `set Friend1Stat=on`. Moreover, your code does not constitute a [mcve]: for instance, missing initial setting and `:TESTFORFRIENDS` label. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: those are included in the code. But i cannot include them as it contains personal information and ftp sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered something in the rainmeter log files:

```
Rainmeter: Debugging: ITCMD has sent an invalid notification type
```

I realized that the numbers for "style" went up to 3 4 and 5 when I would use Find and replace to replace all the numbers in `%friend2%` or `%Friend2Name%` as well! Thanks for your help anyways. Hope this helps anyone else!